# Improving mask in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, masking

I have created a mask with the NIR band to separate earth from the sea.

How can I delete little spot area (errors)  in the mask or change the  pixel value of these spot areas ?

Comment: I guess you will need 2 tools for your mask : one for the pixel inside (saga close gaps type : https://gisgeography.com/how-to-fill-nodata-raster-data/) and one for the isolated external pixels (majority filter type)

Answer (score 2):

Sieve helps you get rid of some of the salt'n'pepper, usually up to 8 pixels. Keep in mind that this also simplifies your coastline.